# UDF Excel Using Vlookup? JavaScript API

Tags: excel, office-js, custom-functions-excel

How do I call this on my Excel spreadsheet? Rick assisted me below with the following code, but how do I call this? I am trying to VLOOKUP numOfParts (which is asked in parameter) and return finalInspectionPerPart.

```
async function inspectionMins(numOfParts) {

  try {
    let finalInspectionPerPart;
    const procEff = 0.72;

    await Excel.run(async function (context) {
      const range = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("A1:B9");
      finalInspectionPerPart = context.workbook.functions.vlookup(numOfParts, range, 2, false);
      finalInspectionPerPart.load('value');
      await context.sync();
      return (finalInspectionPerPart.value / procEff);
    })
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to work with your code because we don't have sample data for A1:B9. As a first attempt of doing what you seem to want to do with ES6 syntax, try:

```
async function inspectionMins(numOfParts) {

  try {
    let finalInspectionPerPart;
    const procEff = 0.72;

    await Excel.run(async function (context) {
      const range = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("A1:B9");
      finalInspectionPerPart = context.workbook.functions.vlookup(numOfParts, range, 2, false);
      finalInspectionPerPart.load('value');

      await context.sync();
      return (finalInspectionPerPart.value / procEff);
    })
  } catch (error) {
      // handle error
  };  
}
```

You will need to call this function with the `await` keyword:

```
await inspectionMins(5);
```

Comment: Hi Rick! Thank you for this! I have attached a picture for example data. Where do I call the function with the await keyword? Thanks

Comment: Hi Rick, I still am confused about calling await inspectionMins(5);. How do I call this in Excel?

Comment: Are you creating a custom function? If so, then maybe the following article will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/call-excel-apis-from-custom-function.